# A tag <section> substitui a <main>?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Estou começando a usar HTML5 e ainda não sei bem como escolher entre as tags `<main>` e `<section>`.

Vejo pessoas usando depois do header o `<main>`, enquanto outras já usam o `<section>`. Queria saber qual é a mais apropriada para fazer o conteúdo do meio da pagina.

Por exemplo:

```
<header> ... </header>

<main> ou <section> ???

<footer> ... </footer>
```

Comment: Um bom lugar para consultar sobre cada tag com explicações de uso "ideal" é no MDN, exemplo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Answer (score 7):

Do ponto de vista semântico, não. As tags `<main>` e `<section>` têm significados diferentes para o HTML5, que se baseia em ideias de estrutura semântica.

- De acordo com a documentação, [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) representa o conteúdo **dominante** da página. Essa seção deve idealmente conter o tópico central do documento ou a funcionalidade central de uma aplicação. Deve ser único.
- Já [`<section>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) representa uma seção menos hierarquicamente importante. É, pela definição, uma “seção genérica do documento”, que não tem outro elemento semântico que melhor a represente.

**Portanto, `<section>` não substitui `<main>`.** A já referida documentação do `<section>` é enfática em dizer que esta tag deve ser utilizada apenas quando nenhum outro elemento melhor representar semanticamente o conteúdo.

Como `<main>` é um elemento que indica a semântica de conteúdo principal, deve ser preferido sobre `<section>`.

---

Quanto ao exemplo de código colocado na pergunta, não tenho como responder de maneira que cobre 100% dos casos, já que a escolha depende do conteúdo da página. De modo geral, se o conteúdo depois do `<header>` for o principal da página, `<main>` deve ser usado.

Caso contrário, talvez `<section>` faça sentido, mas nesse caso idealmente outra seção da página deve ser a “dominante”, isto é, `<main>`.